# Remote node signature for HTLC-success and HTLC-timeout transactions

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing, hash-time-locked-contract

According to BOLT #3, when constructing a HTLC output in the version of the local node (both received and offered HTLC), it requires that the payment to the local node is locked with `CHECKMULTISIG` opcode that requires both `localhtlcsig` and `remotehtlcsig` in order to spend it.

As far as what I have seen, nodes do not exchange their htlcsignatures (although we can derive the htlc public keys through basepoint).

So the question: suppose after I receive an HTLC from a node and I successfully pass it to the other nodes, the node that sent the HTLC to me became unresponsive. Now I will need to broadcast my version of the commitment transaction to the Bitcoin blockchain so that I can claim the funds that are locked with the `payment_hash` (when I receive one). But, in order to spend that output, my witness stack will need to have `0 <remotehtlcsig> <localhtlcsig> <payment_preimage>`. Now, if the remote node is offline, how will I get my hands on the `remotehtlcsig` in order to get back the funds locked in the HTLC?

Just to provide additional details, below is a local node version of the received HTLC output according to BOLT #3

```
# To remote node with revocation key
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(SHA256(revocationpubkey))> OP_EQUAL
OP_IF
    OP_CHECKSIG
OP_ELSE
    <remote_htlcpubkey> OP_SWAP OP_SIZE 32 OP_EQUAL
    OP_IF
        # To local node via HTLC-success transaction.
        OP_HASH160 <RIPEMD160(payment_hash)> OP_EQUALVERIFY
        2 OP_SWAP <local_htlcpubkey> 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
    OP_ELSE
        # To remote node after timeout.
        OP_DROP <cltv_expiry> OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY OP_DROP
        OP_CHECKSIG
    OP_ENDIF
OP_ENDIF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as what I have seen, nodes do not exchange their htlcsignatures (although we can derive the htlc public keys through basepoint).

I believe you have overlooked the [`commitment signed message` from bolt 02](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/02-peer-protocol.md#committing-updates-so-far-commitment_signed). From there I quote:

> When a node has changes for the remote commitment, it can apply them, sign the resulting transaction (as defined in BOLT #3), and send a commitment_signed message.

```
type: 132 (commitment_signed)
data:
[32:channel_id]
[64:signature]
[2:num_htlcs]
[num_htlcs*64:htlc_signature]
```

While we already see that signatures for all htlcs are transferred we can find the requirements further down :

> A sending node:
>   ... 
>   MUST include one htlc_signature for every HTLC transaction corresponding to the ordering of the commitment transaction (see BOLT #3).

I believe a node SHOULD NOT  forward the htlc before it validated the signatures from all the htlcs of the received commitment signed.